# Find all non-negative integral solutions to the equation $2013^q+2014^w=2015^r$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, contest-math, exponential-diophantine-equations

> Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of nonnegative integers.  Find all solutions $(q, r, w) \in \mathbb{N}^3$ to the equation $$2013^q+2014^w=2015^r.$$

Can someone explain me this solution ? one can post other solutions too..

$2013^q + 2014^w = 2015^r$.

Let us say that $(q, r, w) \in \mathbb{N}^3$.

We see that $r \geq 2$.

Hence, $\min\{ \nu _{31}(LHS)\} = 2$.

We see that $2013 \equiv -2 \pmod{961}$ and $2014 \equiv -1 \pmod{961}$.

Hence, we require $2013^q \equiv 960$ or $1 \pmod{961}$.

But, we see by the cycle of modulo of powers of $-2$ $\pmod{961}$ that this condition is never satisfied.

Hence, we get that the only triplet is $(q, w, r) = (0, 1, 1)$.

Comment: What part don't you get?  Note;  the first line, "We see that $r≥2$" is confusing (especially since $r=1$ in the final answer).  I believe what they meant to say was "Suppose that $r≥2$ (we'll derive a contradiction)".

Comment: how did they get v_31(LHS)=2 ? , also how did 31 came from ?

Comment: If $r≥2$ then the right side is divisible by $31^2$, since $2015=5\times 13\times 31$.  Since the right side is divisible by $31^2$, the left side must be as well.

Comment: I don't understand the part where it says, $2013 \equiv -2 \pmod{961}$

Comment: @saulspatz  Now there's a good point.  They seem to have made that stuff up.  It is true that $2013\equiv -2\pmod {31}$ though.

Comment: Note that 2014^w = 1 or -1 mod 961 , and 2015^r = 0 mod 961 (if r >1 )

Comment: @saulspatz  Nor does their remark on the powers of $-2$ make sense.  $(-2)^{310}\equiv 1 \pmod {961}$.  So, I don't think this "solution" has a lot of value.

Comment: @lulu you are correct this solution is a fake solve.. OP if you don't mind  can you say the source ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually , this is a pretty fun problem , which plays with modulos so much .

Solution: $\boxed{(q, w, r) = (0, 1, 1)}$

Note that $r>0 $ .

Also, note that $w>0$, (if not then $2013^q$ is odd, $2014^w=1$ and $2015^r$ is odd, not possible as RHS is even and LHS is odd )

**Claim**: $q=0$

**Proof**: let's say for contradiction , assume that q /ge 1

then $2013^q \equiv 0 \pmod 3$

and $2014^w \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

So we have $2013^q + 2014^w \equiv 1 mod 3 \implies r$ is even.

Let $r=2b$ .

Now, let us look at the unit digits.

we see that $2013^q$ ends with $3,9,7,1$ and $2014^w$ ends with $4,6$ and $2015^r$ ends with $5$.

By calculations, we get that q must be even , hence let $q=2a$.

Hence we have $$ 2013^{2a} + 2014^w =2015^{2b} \implies 2014^w=2015^{2b}-2013^{2a}\implies 2014^w= (2015^b-2103^a)(2015^b+2103^a) \implies 2^w \cdot 19^w \cdot 53^w = (2015^b-2103^a)(2015^b+2103^a)$$

Let $\alpha=(2015^b+2103^a)$ and $\beta=(2015^b-2103^a)$.

Clearly $\alpha>\beta$.

let $d=\text{gcd($\alpha,\beta$)}$

Note that $d\mid 2014^w$ and $d\mid (\alpha +\beta)=2\cdot 2015^b \implies d=1$ or $2$ .

Now, since $\alpha>\beta$ , and $d= 1$ or $2$, we get that $v_{53}(\alpha)=w$ and $v_{19}(\beta)=w $.

Now, in $\alpha , 2015^b \equiv 1 \pmod {53}$ , since $2015 \equiv 1 \pmod {53} $.

Since $2015^b - 2013^a \equiv 0 \pmod 53 \implies a$ is odd .

In $\beta, 2015^b \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$ , since $2015 \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$ .

Now, since $a$ is odd $ \implies 2013^a \equiv -1 \pmod {19} \implies \beta \equiv 2 \pmod {19}   \implies  v_{19}(\beta)=w=0$ , a contradiction, since in the first observation,we noted that $w>0$ .

Hence $q=0$

**Main Proof**:

So, we have $1+2014^w=2015^r$ . Note that $r$ is odd since $1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3, 2014\equiv 1 \pmod 3 $.

hence $2014^w=2015^r-1=2014(2015^{r-1} +\dots +1)$ .

But note $2015^{r-1} +\dots +1$ ( since $r$ is odd) .

Hence $w=1$  .

Hence $2013^q+2014^w=2013^0+2014^1= 1+2014 =2015 \implies r=1$.

And we are done!I hope someone can verify this solution .

Comment: well v_53 , means highest power of 53 , right ?

Comment: @raheel yes.............